# How do I get my C program to ignore whitespace(spaces, tabs, newlines)?

Tags: c

Im new to programming with C and I'm having a hard time coming up with the proper formula to where it ignores, spaces, tabs, and new lines when I enter a string

[My Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTnuD.png)

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image. Copy-paste the code here and don't forget to format it as code using CTRL+K

Comment: If we need to be able to modify your example, don't you think it'd be best use of our time to be able to copy/paste it? Do you expect our search engine to extract keywords from your image in order to be indexed for usefulness to future visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `else specialCharacter++;` with `else if(!isspace(str[x])) specialCharacter++;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see for spaces, tab, new lines in a string by taking each character and checking for them and then doing appropriate operations if necessary.
Here is the code which is in alignment with your code.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    int main(void){
      char str[1000];
      int x,lowerCase,upperCase,digit,specialCharacter,total;
      printf("Enter a string");
      gets(str);
      x = lowerCase = upperCase = digit = specialCharacter = total =0;
      for(;str[x]!='\0';x++){
        if(str[x] >= 'A' && str[x] <='Z') upperCase++;
        else if(str[x] >= 'a' && str[x] <='z') lowerCase++;
        else if(str[x] >= '0' && str[x] <='9') digit++;
        else if(str[x] == '\n' || str[x] == '\t' || str[x] == ' '){}
        else specialCharacter++;
      }
      total = lowerCase + upperCase + digit + specialCharacter;
      printf("lowercase= %d , uppercase=%d , digit=%d , special=%d \n", lowerCase,upperCase,digit,specialCharacter );
      printf("%d",total);
      return 0;
    }
```